# On the etymology of "Stereophonic"

Tags: etymology

I've taken a dive into the field of "stereolithography" of late. If I am not entirely wrong that "translates" to "durable stone writing." And that makes a lot of sense, given what stereolithography actually is.

But what of "Stereophonic"? "Durable sound?" Why "Durable" in that context?

Comment: Have you tried looking up the prefix *stereo*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stereo in stereophonic refers to the *three-dimensional sense*:

> [Stereophonic sound](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereophonic_sound) or, more commonly, stereo, is a method of sound reproduction that creates an illusion of multi-directional audible perspective. (Wikipedia)

[Stereo](https://www.etymonline.com/word/stereo-?ref=etymonline_crossreference) (etymology)

> before vowels stere-, word-forming element meaning "solid, firm; three-dimensional; stereophonic," from Greek stereos "solid". (Etymonline)